# find which column via a cell, then get a row based on an index match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Please Note:** Its a confidential work document, and will not allow Macro's (Or else I could do it myself haha!)

**Objective:**
Trying to use formula's to find which column a date is in, then convert it to the column letter.
Then need to match the name in a row, and get the data from Row and Column

**Document Contains:**
I have a Date in B3. I want to find what Column that date belongs to on 'Sheet4' on Row 2.
I then want to find what row Employee is ('Sheet1'!B172) on in 'Sheet4'

**Currently got:**
`=CHAR(64 + MATCH($B$3,'Sheet4'!$2:$2,0)) & MATCH(B172,'Sheet4'!$B$3:$B$36,0)` which has returned D1 (Correct Column & Row) but now unsure on how I can use that to get the results of 'Sheet4'!D1

I'm now at a lost of how to make the formula return the text, and I'm sure its something simple, and I've tried google, but everything I've tried hasn't worked. Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong, and where I need to start looking to get it working properly?

Comment: if you can get the row and column (which you said you can) then you can use OFFSET from Cell A1 with row and column offsets.

Comment: so, I tried `=OFFSET('Sheet4'!1:9999,10,D)` and it returned a #NAME? error, so I then tried `=OFFSET('Sheet4'!1:9999,10,4)` and that returned a #REF! error.

I looked on the Microsoft Support Website regarding the OFFSET funciton, and it said to use the numbers, so goodbye the D for column, but I thought I had matched the function properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use 4 for the column, instead of D?

Comment: `'Sheet4'!1:9999` will grab all the data that I require. Should I change it to `'Sheet4'!A1:AH9999` ?

Comment: Well just do what works.

Comment: For OFFSET you don't want to offset from a large, square range of cells. You want to offset from a cell - the top left corner of your square. In this case, Sheet4!:A1. INDEX would work pretty much the same way.

Comment: By way of comparison: OFFSET (from a cell): `=OFFSET($A$1,1,1)`, and INDEX (within a range): `=INDEX($A$1:$B$2,2,2)` -- both of these formulas refer to B2.

Comment: I just somehow got it to work with Index via `=INDEX('Sheet4'!A:S,MATCH(B172,'Sheet4'!$B$1:$B$36,0),MATCH($B$3,'Sheet4'!$2:$2,0))`

It didn't work before but I may have misspelt it!